# c++ vector comparison with user defined classes? (==, <, >)

Tags: c++, vector, comparison, operator-keyword, stdvector

trying to compare two vectors of a user defined class, like so:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct ExampleClass {
    bool operator==(ExampleClass right) {
        return true;
    }
};
int main() {
    if (vector<ExampleClass>() == vector<ExampleClass>())
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

I can't seem to get it to work just using the < operator of the user defined class; I can however get it to work by writing a custom operator to compare between two vectors of said class, but I'm unclear as to whether this is what must be done or if I'm just misunderstanding the vector comparison operators.
I'd also like to have it work with < and > if possible. I could just write one template operator for the comparison of two vectors to have them compare each element - but this all seems like a workaround for me not understanding something.
Please explain to me what I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: I'm aware, this is of course not the actual code I want to use, I'm just trying to get it to compile so I know how to use vector comparison. I did also just realise that I meant to use operator== in the example, I've changed it now.

Comment: Please post the full error message you received, or describe the symptoms of the problem.

Comment: You need at minimum `operator==` and `operator<`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp Example: https://ideone.com/rA2z4g

Comment: After fixing obvious syntax errors, your code [compiles for me](https://rextester.com/EVU14136)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct ExampleClass {
    bool operator==(ExampleClass right) const {
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    return (vector<ExampleClass>() != vector<ExampleClass>())
}
```